# What is MINGWDIR?

Tags: qt, mingw

While building Qt and Qt-based software on windows, it seems important to set `MINGWDIR` environment variable. But i'm not very pleased with doing something like 'voodoo magic', without knowing the reasons. Unfortunately, searching google reveals that it's a lot of tutorials and examples that sets `MINGWDIR`, but no documentation about this environment variable itself. Is it required by mingw32-make? Is it required by Qt? Is it not required at all? Maybe some guru knows WHAT exactly this environment variable is for and can point me to some mingw/gcc documentation or any article about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you know, MinGW is a compiler.  This enironment variable is used to point to the installation folder for it.

Does [this](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/InstallationHOWTOforMinGW) article help ?

Comment: This article is good, but it don't mention a 'MINGWDIR' :(. It will be ideal if some mingw documentation states something like 'mingw uses MINGWDIR to locate header and library files'. But i can't find such information :(. So right now it's unclear to me if MINGWDIR is used by mingw, by Qt or not needed at all :(.